# Setting an ASIHTTPRequest post to a SimpleHTTPServer Python server?

Tags: iphone, python, asihttprequest

I am working on a project (that i will not be releasing to the app store - just for fun) that will upload an image via an HTTP Post request from my iPhone to a server that I have running the Python script SimpleHTTPServer(http://ubuntuguide.net/http-server-support-uploading-files-from-windows-in-ubuntu).  I have successfully used the ASIHTTP APIs in the past for text strings, but can't for the life of me figure out how to upload an image.  This is what I am currently using:

```
-(void)processRequest {

    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mySimpleHTTPServer"]]; 
    [request setFile:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.png"] withFileName:@"Image.png" andContentType:@"image/png" forKey:@"file"];

    [request startSynchronous]; 
    NSLog(@"%@",[request responseString]);
    NSUserDefaults *profiles = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [profiles setObject:[request responseString] forKey:@"response"];
    [profiles synchronize];

    [self performSelector:@selector(endRequest) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];

}
```

Really, the only part that I am assuming I am wrong about is the :

```
[request setFile:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.png"] withFileName:@"Image.png" andContentType:@"image/png" forKey:@"file"];
```

Any thoughts on where i could be going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

As @SorinA. mentions, you should supply a *file path* as the first argument to `setFile:withFileName:andContentType:forKey:`. In your example, you're supplying a `UIImage` object instead.

The simplest fix, however, might be to just use `setData:withFileName:andContentType:forKey:`. You just need to convert your `UIImage` object to its `NSData` representation:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.png"]);
[request setData: imageData
    withFileName: @"Image.png"
  andContentType: @"image/png"
          forKey: @"file"];
```

Also, your URL looks a bit odd ("mySimpleHTTPServer"), I assume this is just a placeholder for a URL in the form of "http://localhost:some_port/some_path"? Definitely confirm that your Python web server is actually seeing the request.

Comment: I verified this by testing my code with a late 2010 version of ASI vs. a later version.  The older one accepts NSData and knows what to do with it using setFile, while the newer one requires setData! Thats why some examples use setFile.  This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Offhand, I don't see an obvious problem, but I would try calling [request responseStatusCode] and [request responseStatusMessage] instead of [request responseString].  I'm guessing that the the response to a post would not have a string.  I think it should return 200 or something like that to indicate success.

You can also try:

```
if(request.error) {
    NSLog("ERROR: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Lastly.. I would look at ASIHTTPRequestConfig.h   I'm using ASI as well, so I just peeked at it and it has some debug options that should help.

set the 0's to 1s:

```
DEBUG_FORM_DATA_REQUEST 1
DEBUG_REQUEST_STATUS 1
```

If you haven't tried those, that should give you some info.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use ASIFormDataRequest?

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request addData:imageData withFileName:@"mypicture.png" andContentType:@"image/png" forKey:@"photos"];
```

Comment: I used [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.png"] as the imageData and it crashed the app.

Comment: ...and yes, I have been using ASIFormDataRequest.  I pasted the entire method above.

Comment: @Rob, You said that you were using setFile, not addData.

Answer (score 0):

in your code why do you use setData and setFile on the same request? If you are sending large files you should use “setFile” instead of “setData”. Files are then read from disk instead of memory.

when you are setting content type you should set the correct values.

> [request setFile:path
>   withFileName:@"Image.png"
>   andContentType:@"image/jpeg"
>             forKey:@"file"];

content type should be image/png .

to upload an image i use this code:

```
// Initilize Queue
[networkQueue setUploadProgressDelegate:statusProgressView];
[networkQueue setRequestDidFinishSelector:@selector(imageRequestDidFinish:)];
[networkQueue setQueueDidFinishSelector:@selector(imageQueueDidFinish:)];
[networkQueue setRequestDidFailSelector:@selector(requestDidFail:)];
[networkQueue setShowAccurateProgress:true];
[networkQueue setDelegate:self];

 NSString *imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myImage.jpg"];
 url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myserver/upload.php"];
 ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];
 [request setPostValue:@"myImageName" forKey:@"name"]; 
 [request setFile:imagePath forKey:@"photo"];

 [networkQueue addOperation:request];
 [networkQueue go];
```

Also, if you are uploading several photos at once, use setFile:forKey: rather than setData:forKey:. This way, ASIFormDataRequest will know you’re sending a fair bit of data, and it will stream the request data from a temporary file on disk, which means you don’t need to keep lots of image data in memory.

Comment: I have never used networkQueue before - I have always just used ASIFormDataRequest by itself for sending simple strings.  This may be the correct solution but I have no idea how to implement it.

Comment: Hi Rob, here is an example of using an ASINetworkQueue ( https://gist.github.com/150447 ). in the example they use a ASIHTTPRequest you can change that with the type you need.